# Core data one-to-many relationships

Tags: ios, core-data

I've been searching around the internet for days looking for tutorials on how to work with two entities and adding values for the data and linking them. Here is how my app is set up:

I'm making an app that allows the user to create an athlete and within that athlete they can add multiple sporting events. I have two entities: `Athletes` and `Events` with a to-one relation from `Athletes` to `Events` and a to-many relationship inversely.

The issue I'm having is what code to write to add the `name` and `opponent` attribute values within the `Events` entitiy, all while making sure that that specific name and opponent match up to only one athlete. I've tried using Core Data Accessor Methods, as well as creating new NSManagedObjects for either entitity and adding the values for specific keys.

I've tried to follow the CoreDataRecipes sample code, as well as the common Core Data tutorials on the web. Can anyone help steer me in the right path with some basic method functions or other tutorials that helped you? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify with an example what is going wrong. i.e. what you did, what you expected to happen, what actually happened. That way we know exactly what it is you are asking for help with. :)

Comment: Well my app is set up where in one view you create the athlete and select them as "active" and then in another view, I have a tableview controller that you can create multiple events under each specific athlete that was recently selected. Basically, I'm expecting to retrieve the text from two textfields and add those strings to my entity so they can create a table. I guess I'm confused on the whole programmatic side on using relationships and add multiples objects in one entity and linking them to one object in another. I understand the data model diagram fine though. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please, add visual structure of your Core Data model. And have you been look on this series of tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop thinking in terms of RDBMS (relational databases) and start thinking in terms of managed object models. CoreData deals with managing objects and their associations. You can associate Athlete objects to Event objects (by the way I suggest using singular vs. plural for entity names i.e. Athlete and Event vs. Athletes and Events and use singular for to-one relationships and plural for to-many relationships). It's a preference thing but I refer to myself as an Athlete (object) not an Athletes (objects). Makes it all more readable and intuitive as well.

Assuming your entities look like this given how you described the relationships:

```
    @interface Athlete : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    //... a bunch more attributes
    @property (nonatomic, retain) Event *event;  // use singluar for relationship name too
    //...
    @end

    @interface Event : NSManagedObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * eventName;
    //... a bunch more attributes
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *athletes; // use plural for relationship name
    //...
    @end

    @implementation MyViewController
    //... some method
    // fetch the athletes (possibly present in table view or other mechanism for selection)
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Athlete"];
    NSArray *athletes = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    // select the althletes (primary & opponent - hardcoded for example)
    //... 
    NSArray *selectedAthletes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: athletes[0], athletes[1], nil];

    // create an event
    Event *event = [NSEntityDescription
                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event"
                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
    // add the athletes
    [event addAthletes:[NSSet setWithArray:selectedAthletes]];
    //...   
@end
```

Now you have an event with the 2 athletes. If you wanted to distinguish between the opponent and challenger then you could create 2 to-one relationships (from Event to Athlete) such as opponent and challenger and associate the Event to the Athlete via something like:

```
@interface Event : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * eventName;
//... a bunch more attributes
@property (nonatomic, retain) Athlete *opponent; // use singluar for relationship name
@property (nonatomic, retain) Athlete *challenger; 
//...
@end

//...
event.opponent = athletes[0];
event.challenger = athletes[1];
//...
```